# In a shader, why does substituting a variable with the expression producing it cause different behaviour?

Tags: opengl, shaders

I have this correctly-working OpenGL shader producing Perlin noise:

```
 float left = lerp(fade(v),  downleft,  topleft);
 float right = lerp(fade(v), downright, topright);
 float result = lerp(fade(u), left, right);
```

Then I tried plugging the definitions of `right` and `left` into `result`:

```
float result = lerp(fade(u),
                    lerp(fade(v), downleft,  topleft),
                    lerp(fade(v), downright, topright));
```

Surprisingly, this behaves completely differently, giving visible edges in my Perlin noise. Below are both results:

[image]

My whole 30-line shader is [here](http://wklej.to/diXAV).

What is the difference between those?

Comment: Some trivia notes -- your lerp() is equivalent to the built-in function mix().
And, it may be handy to put your shader into ShaderToy, as a convenient way for others to easily run/debug it.

(That all said, I'm so far mystified why the substitution would do what it seems to be doing.)

Comment: I bet that you're taking coordinates from each render in one of them and screen in the other.

Comment: @Lolums 34 can you rephrase? I did not quite get you.

Comment: @hungry91 ignore that comment, it's invalid. I'll try to answer the question later though when I get some time :)

Comment: I'm unable to recreate this. Are you sure you didn't accidentally plug `left` in twice or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the processing system is loosing floating point precision because you're not declaring memory for the variable. 
Normally this isn't a problem, however it seems that your lerp function requires a good bit of precision.
Imagine this: computers cannot know irrational numbers.
So if X is the square root of 5, and Y is the square root of 3.
Saying X + Y is different than sqrt(5) + sqrt(3)

This is because on the lower level  the data in the first operation goes

data > memory > cpu > memory

And in the second operation it's more like

Data > cpu > memory

While faster, this operation results in precision loss, especially in 32 bit systems.